# Oculus touch controller Local Avatar is in Pink?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

The oculus hand controllers on Unity which is represented by "Local Avatar" has its material in pink color.

I have tried to change the material but no luck.

A week ago it was working fine but after I integrated the latest Oculus Integration from Unity store, it has become this way.

Answer (score 1):

Pink color represents a shader that is missing. re-import the pack or change the shader to standard to test.

Comment: Not really it is default in it and I have tried to even reimport it but the problem persists.